# Email sending in HTML

Tags: html, email

I wanted to send simple html code to email but in outlook it apears as a html code not images and text styled.

Should I include any more code so that outlook would recognize it as email and will not display the message as html code?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Dragooon</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#e2e3e7" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<table id="Table_01" width="602" align="center" height="3401" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="10">
            <img style="display:block" src="/images/Concept1_01.gif" width="1" height="394" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="47">
            <img style="display:block" src="/images/Concept1_02.gif" width="600" height="56" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img style="display:block" src="/images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="56" alt=""></td>
    </tr><td>
            <img style="display:block" src="/images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *How* are you sending the email? Is this a programming question or a question about using Outlook?

Comment: I'd expect you to see the code and not the rendered HTML if you pasted that into gmail's compose box, which is a WYSWYG editor.  Also, your image sources should be absolute locations, starting with your domain.

Comment: Need example. I think I know, but not sure.

Comment: Are you asking how to stop the email from sending the pictures/HTML or are you trying to make it display correctly?

Comment: well when i send it to outlook it just display the html code and not what it represents, so I am trying to make it display corectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your images are missing because you need to add the domain in front of it for example:

```
    <td rowspan="10">
        <img style="display:block" src="http://test.com/images/Concept1_01.gif" width="1" height="394" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="47">
        <img style="display:block" src="http://test.com/images/Concept1_02.gif" width="600" height="56" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img style="display:block" src="http://test.com/images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="56" alt=""></td>
     </tr><td>
        <img style="display:block" src="http://test.com/images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td></td>
```

Comment: yes i know about absolute links but i dont know yet where the files are going to be stored. Thank you anyway

Comment: You could find an image hosting service like tinypic.com

Answer (score 0):

I think this might put you on the right track

http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/html-email.html

Comment: Yep, it has to do with the settings in outlook. Or Try and uncheck: Tools > Options > Preferences > email Options > Read all mail in plain text depending on your version.